# Android.mk output function info only prints single line

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, android-source, android.mk

I am using some shell commands in the Android.mk, like

```
$(shell rm -rfv $(TARGET_OUT)/xxx)
```

And I want to see the command out put during the building process. However, the out put is always single line when I use either

```
$(info $(shell rm -frv $(TARGET_OUT)/www))
```

or

```
$(info "$(shell rm -frv $(TARGET_OUT)/www)")
```

The result is like

```
removed `out/target/product/xxx/system/xxx/xxx.xxx' removed directory: `out/target/product/xxx/system/xxx/xxx'
```

instead of

```
removed `out/target/product/xxx/system/xxx/xxx.xxx' 
removed directory: `out/target/product/xxx/system/xxx/xxx'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? I very much doubt `$(shell rm ...)` in the makefile is the best choice.

Comment: It is simple to copy/remove a folder, at least simpler than writing a large file list and call something like LOCAL_COPY_FILES

Comment: Yes, it's probably simpler, but it's not correct and will sooner or later get you in trouble.

Comment: Understand the risk, however, is there any simple method to copy a large folder with thousands of files to the target?

Comment: Sure, you can e.g. use `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` and generate the list of files to copy with the help of `$(wildcard ...)` or `$(shell find ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

That simply isn't possible with GNU Make, because the output of $(shell ) is always expanded in a way that replaces newlines with spaces. This is intentional by the way.

Generally speaking, doing any kind of changes on the filesystem with $(shell ...) commands is a bad idea, because some of these changes will not be visible to GNU Make when it later tries to compute dependencies / which actions to run. This can result in unpredictable behaviour in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I fully agree with you, although my problem/question cannot be solved. Up vote for you.